# Read/Write BMP/PNG grey scale image with C or C++

Tags: c++, c, image-processing

*I'm rewording it because someone thougth it was "off topic" and some other rude responses without thinking about my efforts and all the searches, many thanks to locking me for 4 days just because 2 of you thought I didn't write a single line of code*

*I will write my puny failures and be assured, i used the search button*

I'm doing an imageprocessing project in C and CUDA. I knew the core of the problem but I encountered a little problem

**read and write a grey scale image (PNG or BMP) as input&output**

My "think about it later" strategy was the same of my colleagues:

1) use a Matlab script using: `[X,map] = imread('xray.png');`

map is pretty useless with a grey scale (useful for RGB files) but X returned me a Width x Height matrix with intergers as a various scale of "brightness"

2) use the fprintf function in Matlab to write a xray.txt with 3 lines:

1. Width
2. Heigth
3. Width*Heigth line of integers separated with a space

3) import the data in C like this:

```
        FILE *image;
        image = fopen("xray.txt","r");
        width=fscanf(image,"%f\n",&width);
        heigth=fscanf(image,"%f\n",&heigth);
        pixels=(float *) calloc(width*heigth, sizeof(float));
        for (int i = 0; i < width*heigth; i++) {
        fscanf(image,"%f ",&pixels[i]);
        }
        fclose(image);
```

4) **OFFTOPIC** core of the image processing algorithm where I **NEED** a 1D float array (the second version of the code is in CUDA). I need the code to be the same, for the time of processing confrontation

5) reverse process: from width, height, pixels, i write a xrayout.txt, xrayedges.txt

6) second MatLab script that from xrayout.txt & xrayedges.txt generate xrayout.bmp & xrayedges.bmp.. Not worth posting, it's the reverse process of imRead

The project itslef is complete, it all works well but it really nags me that I couldn't find an "only C" solution

Do someone know some easy way to read and write a grey scale PNG knowing: width, heigth, pixel values?
Is there a function that can import BMP o PNG images?
It doesn't matter if it need a 2D array, i can work my way out

**NOTE 1: by easy way i mean "vanilla C", without using some exotic libraries o other languages (if so, I will stick with the MatLab scripts)**

**NOTE 2: i TRIED (with multiple failures) and searched in stackoverflow and google, posting this post is my last possibility, so please be gentle**

Comment: Sure, there is a function in standard C for every task one can think of. Just use the `do_what_i_want`-function. Seriously: Your question is far off-topic. That could have been answered by a simple search.

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, that C/C++ language actually might have such a function. But the two **different** languages C and C++ don't.

Comment: You can use the PGM format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) it is exactly what you describe. Also I doubt there is a built-in function in C about loading specific image format :) But you can write a loader routine yourself, it will be a couple of fscanf() calls (or file stream readings for C++).

Comment: You should show some own effort to solve your problem.
This can be done without any non-standard libraries both in C and C++
The only thing you have to do is use google or read the Bitmap file specification and implement your stuff accordingly.

And why would you put integer values between 0 and 255 into a float array? (Hint 0-255 can be covered with 1 byte)

Comment: @Olaf
I posted it after reading all the searches. I put some effort and seemed useless posting the failures.
Thanks for looking down on me.

Comment: @Piglet 
I need a float because after the anisotropic i need a "threshold confront" to decide between a second step of diffusion or going through edge detection

Comment: I reworded my question, could you please reopen it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{ //BITMAPFILEHEADER
  char  bfType[2];
  int   bfSize;
  short bfReserved1;
  short bfReserved2;
  int   bfOffBits;
  //BITMAPINFOHEADER
  int   biSize;
  int   biWidth;
  int   biHeight;
  short biPlanes;
  short biBitCount;
  int   biCompression;
  int   biSizeImage;
  int   biXPelsPerMeter;
  int   biYPelsPerMeter;
  int   biClrUsed;
  int   biClrImportant;
} bmpInfo;

#pragma pack()

int imageInfo(bmpInfo *img)
{
  int offset = 0;
  printf("------------------------------------------------------------- BITMAPFILEHEADER\n");
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) bfType           %8c%c (0x%04X)\n", offset, offset, img->bfType[0], img->bfType[1], *(short *)img->bfType);
  offset += sizeof img->bfType;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) bfSize           %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset,  img->bfSize, img->bfSize);
  offset += sizeof img->bfSize;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) bfReserved1      %9hd (0x%04hX)\n", offset, offset,  img->bfReserved1, img->bfReserved1);
  offset += sizeof img->bfReserved1;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) bfReserved2      %9hd (0x%04hX)\n", offset, offset,  img->bfReserved2, img->bfReserved2);
  offset += sizeof img->bfReserved2;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) bfOffBits        %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset,  img->bfOffBits, img->bfOffBits);
  printf("------------------------------------------------------------- BITMAPINFOHEADER\n");
  offset += sizeof img->bfOffBits;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biSize           %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset, img->biSize, img->biSize);
  offset += sizeof img->biSize;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biWidth          %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset, img->biWidth, img->biWidth);
  offset += sizeof img->biWidth;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biHeight         %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset, img->biHeight, img->biHeight);
  offset += sizeof img->biHeight;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biPlanes         %9d (0x%04hX)\n",  offset, offset, img->biPlanes, img->biPlanes);
  offset += sizeof img->biPlanes;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biBitCount       %9d (0x%04hX)\n",  offset, offset, img->biBitCount, img->biBitCount);
  offset += sizeof img->biBitCount;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biCompression    %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset, img->biCompression, img->biCompression);
  offset += sizeof img->biCompression;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biSizeImage      %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset, img->biSizeImage, img->biSizeImage);
  offset += sizeof img->biSizeImage;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biXPelsPerMeter  %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset, img->biXPelsPerMeter, img->biXPelsPerMeter);
  offset += sizeof img->biXPelsPerMeter;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biYPelsPerMeter  %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset, img->biYPelsPerMeter, img->biYPelsPerMeter);
  offset += sizeof img->biYPelsPerMeter;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biClrUsed        %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset, img->biClrUsed, img->biClrUsed);
  offset += sizeof img->biClrUsed;
  printf("0x%08X (%08d) biClrImportant   %9d (0x%08X)\n",   offset, offset, img->biClrImportant, img->biClrImportant);
  return offset;
}

int main(void)
{
  uint32_t RGB565ColorTable[] = {
        0x7E00000, 0xF8000000, 0x001F0000, 0
    };
  uint16_t myData[64];

    for(int i = 0; i<64; i++)
    {
        myData[i] = 0x241B; //Random Color
    }
  const char filename[] = "full.bmp";
  FILE *fichier = fopen(filename, "rb");
  FILE *fptr = fopen("tth.bmp","w+");

  if(!fichier)
    printf ("Erreur a l'ouverture du fichier [%s]\n", filename);
  else
  {
    bmpInfo *img = malloc(sizeof *img);

    if(img)
    {
      int i, tmp, offset;
      printf("\n[%s]\n", filename);
      fread(img, sizeof(bmpInfo), 1, fichier);

      if(img->bfType[0] == 'B' && img->bfType[1] == 'M')
      {
        offset = imageInfo(img);

        if(img->biBitCount == 1)
        {
          printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------- RGBQUAD\n");
          fread(&tmp, sizeof tmp, 1, fichier);
          offset += sizeof img->biClrImportant;
          printf("0x%08X (%08d)                  %9d (0x%08X)\n", offset, offset, tmp, tmp);
          fread(&tmp, sizeof tmp, 1, fichier);
          offset += sizeof tmp;
          printf("0x%08X (%08d)                  %9d (0x%08X)\n", offset, offset, tmp, tmp);

          printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------- BITS\n");
          for(i = 0; i < img->biSizeImage / (int)sizeof tmp; i++)
          {
              char bin[33];
            fread(&tmp, sizeof tmp, 1, fichier);
            offset += sizeof tmp;
            printf("0x%08X (%08d)                   %8d (0x%08X) (%s)\n", offset, offset, tmp, tmp, itoa(tmp, bin, 2));
          }
        }
      }
      free(img);
    }
    fclose(fichier);
  }
    

    if(fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    fwrite(&filename, sizeof(filename), 1, fptr);
    //fwrite(&myInfoHeader, sizeof(myInfoHeader), 1, fptr);
    fwrite(&RGB565ColorTable, sizeof(RGB565ColorTable), 1, fptr);
    fwrite(&myData, sizeof(myData), 1, fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I memorized some rules from C++ too when I was young. Sadly, I need to memorize them again if I am to use them. To answer your question (I'm attempting to do so),

1.) I think you're getting confused with reading an image into C++. Vanilla C++ in itself has no standard libraries to read images, use something like openCV or ITK toolbox to get relevant functions.

2.) Yes you can convert the read image into a 1D float array but there are no in-built ways that would automatically treat that 1D float array as an image, even with external toolboxes present. For eg. you read images into Mat objects in OpenCV: from there onwards, you can do whatever you want with it, even convert it into a really long 1D array. But it wont serve your purpose.

3.) I mean I still cant understand the 1D part, I like old school code too but that's just pushing it, man. In fact I'll say, install OpenCV, and memorize its documentation, you'll be able to do all that you mentioned and even more.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)
I need the 1D part because the second part of the project is transferring the 3 functions for image processing in CUDA, and CUDA don't like 2D arrays

Comment: I think OpenCV has major tie-ups with CUDA in terms of development. Try and see if you can find examples relevant to what you want to do, you might just find the code for it.

Comment: *Sigh* :( if i have to use OpenCV i'd rather stick to my MatLab functions, then read the txt into a float array and viceversa...

My goal was to be the smartass that used only C language

I will look into it :)